# ExtJS 4 Tree Icons

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

How can I change the tree node icons on a per node basis when when the node supports expand/collapse?

For example, I can set the expand/collapse icons globally for the tree using this CSS:

```
#reports-tree .x-tree-icon-parent
{
    background-image: url('../images/tree/folder_closed.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#reports-tree .x-grid-tree-node-expanded .x-tree-icon-parent
{
    background-image: url("../images/tree/folder_opened.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I can also set individual `leaf` icons using `iconCls` as standard.

However, in some cases I have non-leaf nodes that I want to give a custom icon and NOT use the normal expand/collapse icons.

Comment: You want to change the `+` and `-` icons?

Comment: No. I want to change the actual node icon.

Comment: Then change the `iconClass` before rendering. Could you show your JS code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the solution is to drop in `!important` for the icon CSS, e.g:

```
.sg-arp-reports-tree-report-stim {
    background-image: url('../images/tree/report_stim.png') !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

This seems to work as expected and keeps the icon the same regardless of expanded/collapsed or leaf/not-leaf.

Comment: is `sg-arp-reports-tree-report-stim` the default iconClass for non-leaf node? Changing ExtJS core is not a good practice.

Comment: Eh? I'm not changing anything `core` this is just a custom CSS class that's specified for `iconCls`.

Comment: All of the default Ext JS CSS classes start with the `x-` prefix. The sandboxed CSS classes start with `x4-`.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you

```
#helpContentsTree .x-tree-node-expanded  .x-tree-node-icon
{
    background-image: url("test1.gif") !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#helpContentsTree .x-tree-node-collapsed   .x-tree-node-icon
{
    background-image: url("test.jpg") !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```